# Alias anything=<C-a>"sudo "in bash or zsh

Tags: linux, bash, unix, alias, zsh

Are there any ways to alias a string with ^A, ^E, etc? Or something like this via keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Do you mean you want a control-A keypress to run a command? Should any text on the command line be discarded?

Comment: Hi, I can see that you've accepted my answer. Out of curiosity, can you post what you've managed to do with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) to do what you want to do. In Bash, you could use the `bind` [builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) to display (`bind -P`) or modify the readline key bindings. For instance, `bind '"\e[15~":"top\C-m"'` would map <kbd>F5</kbd> to "top\n". You can also use the `inputrc` configuration file to store these settings.

This is not an [alias](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) but it might lead you to what you want.

On `zsh`, things will be slightly different as zsh does not use readline. Instead it uses its own and more powerful zle : the commands and the syntax might be slightly different but the result should be roughly the same.

Answer (score 3):

In zsh I use the following config to make two <kbd>Esc</kbd> do something similar to what you described:

```
sudo-command-line() {
    [[ -z $BUFFER ]] && zle up-history
    [[ $BUFFER != sudo\ * ]] && BUFFER="sudo ${BUFFER% }"
    zle end-of-line
}
zle -N sudo-command-line
bindkey "\e\e" sudo-command-line
```

Answer (score 1):

For zsh use `bindkey -s`

```
bindkey -s "^A" "sudo "
```